# Would like not selected radio buttons should return empty string

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have the following HTML

```
<form id="create_form" name="create_form" action="" method="post">
<input name="type" id="type" value="individuel" type="radio" /> Individuel <br/>
<input name="type" id="type" value="course"     type="radio" /> Course <br/>

<button class="n" type="submit">Create</button>
</form>
```

and when I get the value of the radio buttons, when none have been selected, my JQuery/Ajax script returns the first radio button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#create_form").submit(function() {
    var type = $('input:radio[name=type]:checked').val();
        ...
```

I would like that the users is forced to consider which to select, and not just the default.

How is that done?

**Update**:

I would think that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#create_form").submit(function() {
    var type = $('input:radio[name=type]:checked').val();
```

means to only get the values of the radio buttons in the form with `id="create_form"`.

But because I had forms below (with `<form id="something_else"`) and radio buttons in those forms also with `name="type"` it extracted that value.

Changing `name=type` to `name=cname` in both html and JQuery solved the problem.

Sounds like a bug in JQuery, doesn't it?

Comment: what the heck is this?? `id="type"` id shoud be *unique*

Comment: That is changed now =) I thought `id` was used to CSS style, so it was okay to have them be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try defining the variable like this (to get an empty string):

```
var type = $('input:radio[name=type]:checked').val() || '';
```

Hmmm, ok to answer the question about making a user choose... try this instead:

```
var type = $('input:radio[name=type]:checked').val();
if (typeof type === 'undefined') {
  alert('You must make a choice!'); 
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Even with `var type = $('input:radio[name=type]:checked').val() || '';` do I get the value of the first radio button.

Comment: If the first radio button is checked it will; by default radio buttons should be unchecked... but I'm not sure if that is true across all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

if

```
( ! $("input:radio").is(':checked') )
```

Doesn't work?

You might also try like so:

```
var is_checked = true;
$('input:radio').each(function(){
   is_checked = is_checked && $(this).is(':checked');
});
if ( ! is_checked );
```

Comment: No, that didn't work either. The second code piece returns true for `is_checked` regardlessly.